# Response when you don't understand what's said before ¿..., verdad?

Tags: preguntas, palabras-interrogativas

What are the possible responses to a sentence you don't hear or understand that ends in *¿verdad?*

For example:

> Mañana vas a ..., ¿verdad?

In English you could say something like "Isn't what true?" or "Doing what?"

In Spanish, should you respond *¿Cómo?*, *¿Qué?*, *¿De qué?*, *¿Que qué?* or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably repeat what I heard, but with a question tone in the last part, or adding qué:

> Mañana voy ¿a...?
>   Mañana voy ¿a qué? (or dónde, if it was "vas a algún sitio")